# Validation in Angular2 FormGroup for dynamically added inputs

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I have a  form in which inputs are added on the click of a button.

```
addInput() {
    let input: {} = {
      "text": null
    };
    this.arr.push(domain); 
      let key = 'textC_' + (this.arr.length - 1);
      this.form.controls[key] = new FormControl("", Validators.required)
  }
```

I am using following code to render on HTML:

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <label>Input</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      <ANY *ngFor="let item of arr; let i = index">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 top5">
               <input type="text" formControlName="textC_{{i}}"  id="name" [(ngModel)]="arr[i].text" >
               <div class="help-block" *ngIf="!form.controls.textC_{{i}}.valid  > 
               Value is required
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>
   </ANY>
</div>
</div>
```

How to render validation messages using this approach.

**form.controls.textC_{{i}}.valid**  is not working

Any alternate?

**Using angular rc5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use expression syntax {{}}. The ngIf directive already treats the assignment as an expression. try:

```
<div class="help-block" *ngIf="!form.controls['textC_' + i].valid">
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.